# Erro: "return não deve ser seguida por uma expressão de objeto"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tipagem, return

Estou com essa função que possui um simples cadastro porém não está cadastrando

Minha dúvida seria naquele `return RES;` que dá a mensagem de erro abaixo do código.

```
//botao para cadastrar OS
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool res = false;

            try
            {              
                SqlCommand query = 
                    new SqlCommand("INSERTO INTO gerarOS VALUES (@codOS,@nomeCliente, @modeloMoto, @quilometragem, @dataOS)");

                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", codOS);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeCliente", nomeCliente);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", modeloMoto);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", quilometragem);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", dataOS);
                query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //caso der erro na inserção
                res = false;
            }

            if (conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conexao.Close(); // fecha conexão

            return res;
        }
```

> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
>   Erro  CS0127  Como "GerarOS.Button1_Click(object, EventArgs)" retorna
>   void, uma palavra-chave return não deve ser seguida por uma expressão
>   de
>   objeto    ProjetoOficina  D:\Programação\ProjetoOficina\GerarOS.cs66Ativo

Comment: Duas coisas: 1 - Onde que está o código que abre a conexão pois sem ele não posso consertar o problema com o `SqlCommand` que não grava. 2 - Tire a linha `return res` pois `Button1_Click` é void.

Answer (score 4):

Tem algumas soluções possíveis.

Uma delas é tirar o `res` do `return`, assim ele se conforma com a assinatura do método que tem um `void` e por isso deve retornar nada.

Outra solução seria mudar a assinatura do método para permitir retornar o tipo de `res`, portanto um `bool`. Mas acho que não dá porque o método do evento exige uma assinatura do jeito que está aí.

Uma solução diferente é separar a lógica do *click* do botão da lógica do de negócio que manipula o banco de dados, o que é uma excelente ideia independente do erro que está tendo (mas isso é outro assunto de *design* de aplicação), assim você pode ter a assinatura do método do jeito que quiser e pode ser um `bool`. Claro você terá que saber onde usar este método. Eu imagino que tem algum lugar que já está esperando usar isto, caso contrário está mais perdido do que imagina e esse erro não tem muita importância já que a aplicação está errada de forma muito mais ampla.

Uma solução possível de ter um valor indicando se deu certo é ter uma campo no objeto que seja um `bool` e você guarda o valor lá em vez de retornar no método, mas essa ideia parece bem errada.

Há outros problemas neste código, apesar dele funcionar, se é que funciona (acho que não).

Se deseja saber algo mais do que este erro deixe para outra pergunta, um problema de cada vez.

Comment: Tem mais coisa errada no código, o `SqlCommand.Connection` é nulo.

Comment: Eu escrevi que tem vários erros no código,, não são apenas 2 ou 3. Só tratei do que ele foi mais específico que ele demostrou na pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Dá uma vista de olhos [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0127), se pesquisares pelo código de erro encontras a explicação, problema, numa função "void" não pode retornar nada, estás a retornar um booleano.

Será antes isto.... verifica [nesta página](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) a documentação do SqlCommand. Vai faltar imediatamente antes do ExecuteNonQuery, o comando open connection, command.Connection.Open();

Junto um exemplo da documentação, repara na utilização de context manager ou seja o [using statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), importante para o acesso a "unmanaged resources", lê um pouco sobre isso.

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

NOTA: Não sei onde declaraste a variável conexao, mas coloquei com esta....não estavas a fazer Open connection.
O teu exemplo, corrigido:

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {              
                SqlCommand query = 
                    new SqlCommand("INSERTO INTO gerarOS VALUES (@codOS,@nomeCliente, @modeloMoto, @quilometragem, @dataOS)", conexao);

                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codOS", codOS);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeCliente", nomeCliente);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modeloMoto", modeloMoto);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quilometragem", quilometragem);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataOS", dataOS);
                query.Connection.Open();
                query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //caso der erro na inserção
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                if (conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open) conexao.Close(); // fecha conexão
            } finally {
                if (conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conexao.Close(); // fecha conexão
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

amigo, verifica essas linhas se de fato estão corretas

```
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", codOS);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeCliente", nomeCliente);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", modeloMoto);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", quilometragem);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeOS", dataOS);
```

pois embora vc esteja passando as variaveis certa, a referência dos dados da query estão erradas, o certo seria:

```
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codOS", codOS);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeCliente", nomeCliente);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modeloMoto", modeloMoto);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quilometragem", quilometragem);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataOS", dataOS);
```

confere se isso resolve, e creio que se não for isso, esse erro também iria ocorrer...